Setcap is not allowing qt program to load libraries
For loading libraries  I am doing
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./SupportLibs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Loading of libraries fails when any cap abilities is set for qt application,
sudo setcap =ep Application
If I don't set capabilities it works fine
THIS ERROR OCCURS::
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5multimediawidgets , cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
EDIT 1: after searching on internet for sometime, I found out that , for security reasons LD_LIBRARY_PATH is ignored when application's setuid or setguid bit is set.
And giving capabilities to the application basically does the similar thing, that's why my libraries were not found by the application.reference
EDIT2:
I resolved this problem by creating a file which contains path to my libraries and copying that to /etc/ld.so.conf.d, and ran ldconfig command in terminal , but still my system is not working smoothly it hangs afterwards , I dont know where to search error logs, what is causing it. qt is pain
